# How do I get to AccessToken and IdToken following successful Amazon Cognito Login from iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-sdk

I have been using the following sample to introduce cognito login to my iOS application:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample

This is working well and I am at the point where I have a `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool` object which I can call the `currentUser()` method to access the user.

What I am struggling to find is how I extract both the `AccessToken` and the `IdToken`.

In the android equivalent, the `onSuccess` method of the `AuthenticationHandler` has a `CognitoUserSession` argument which in turn has `getIdToken()` and `getAccessToken()`.

Frustratingly, I see them output as the `AuthenticationResult` in json format in the output window, but I just don't know how to access them programatically?

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out now:

```
func getSession(){
    self.user?.getSession().continueOnSuccessWith { (getSessionTask) -> AnyObject? in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            let getSessionResult = getSessionTask.result
            self.idToken = getSessionResult?.idToken?.tokenString
            self.accessToken = getSessionResult?.accessToken?.tokenString

        })
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, even though you've found it yourself!

Comment: for those of you who come after me and are wondering just like me from where to get the `self.user` property, it comes from here `AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.default().currentUser()` (Swift 5)